# Django TinyMCE adding custom style formats

Tags: python, django, tinymce

I would like to add a custom style format to the TinyMCE editor on my Python Django website, so I can set a block of text to have a custom CSS class.

I am looking at the TinyMCE documentation on `style_formats` and have found this javascript snippet.

How do I write this in Python so I can add this to my `TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG`?

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  style_formats: [
    // Adds a h1 format to style_formats that applies a class of heading
    { title: 'My heading', block: 'h1', classes: 'heading' }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the `TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG` solved my question.

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'style_formats': [
        [{'title':'Dropcap','block':'p','classes':'has-dropcap'}]
    ]
}
```